# Magento 2 how to insert data in custom table?

Tags: magento2, model, resource-model, custom-table

I'm getting an error everytime I send my form in order to store data in a custom table I created.
This is the error:

```
{"0":"M\u00e9todo no v\u00e1lido Transom\\Emall\\Model\\StoreOwner::create","1":"<pre>#1 Transom\\Emall\\Controller\\Index\\SendStoreOwnerForm->execute() called at [generated\/code\/Transom\/Emall\/Controller\/Index\/SendStoreOwnerForm\/Interceptor.php:24]\n#2 Transom\\Emall\\Controller\\Index\\SendStoreOwnerForm\\Interceptor->execute() called at [vendor\/magento\/framework\/App\/Action\/Action.php:108]\n#3 Magento\\Framework\\App\\Action\\Action->dispatch(&Magento\\Framework\\App\\Request\\Http#0000000051f3c66b0000000073cc3fa5#) called at [vendor\/magento\/framework\/Interception\/Interceptor.php:58]\n#4 Transom\\Emall\\Controller\\Index\\SendStoreOwnerForm\\Interceptor->___callParent('dispatch', array(&Magento\\Framework\\App\\Request\\Http#0000000051f3c66b0000000073cc3fa5#)) called at [vendor\/magento\/framework\/Interception\/Interceptor.php:138]\n#5 Transom\\Emall\\Controller\\Index\\SendStoreOwnerForm\\Interceptor->Magento\\Framework\\Interception\\{closure}(&Magento\\Framework\\App\\Request\\Http#0000000051f3c66b0000000073cc3fa5#) called at [vendor\/magento\/framework\/Interception\/Interceptor.php:153]\n#6 Transom\\Emall\\Controller\\Index\\SendStoreOwnerForm\\Interceptor->___callPlugins('dispatch', array(&Magento\\Framework\\App\\Request\\Http#0000000051f3c66b0000000073cc3fa5#), array(array('designLoader', 'customerNotifica...', 'catalog_app_acti...', 'tax-app-action-d...', 'weee-app-action-...', 'storeCheck', 'contextPlugin', 'customer-app-act...'))) called at [generated\/code\/Transom\/Emall\/Controller\/Index\/SendStoreOwnerForm\/Interceptor.php:39]\n#7 Transom\\Emall\\Controller\\Index\\SendStoreOwnerForm\\Interceptor->dispatch(&Magento\\Framework\\App\\Request\\Http#0000000051f3c66b0000000073cc3fa5#) called at [vendor\/magento\/framework\/App\/FrontController.php:159]\n#8 Magento\\Framework\\App\\FrontController->processRequest(&Magento\\Framework\\App\\Request\\Http#0000000051f3c66b0000000073cc3fa5#, &Transom\\Emall\\Controller\\Index\\SendStoreOwnerForm\\Interceptor#0000000051f3c5dd0000000073cc3fa5#) called at [vendor\/magento\/framework\/App\/FrontController.php:99]\n#9 Magento\\Framework\\App\\FrontController->dispatch(&Magento\\Framework\\App\\Request\\Http#0000000051f3c66b0000000073cc3fa5#) called at [vendor\/magento\/framework\/Interception\/Interceptor.php:58]\n#10 Magento\\Framework\\App\\FrontController\\Interceptor->___callParent('dispatch', array(&Magento\\Framework\\App\\Request\\Http#0000000051f3c66b0000000073cc3fa5#)) called at [vendor\/magento\/framework\/Interception\/Interceptor.php:138]\n#11 Magento\\Framework\\App\\FrontController\\Interceptor->Magento\\Framework\\Interception\\{closure}(&Magento\\Framework\\App\\Request\\Http#0000000051f3c66b0000000073cc3fa5#) called at [vendor\/magento\/module-store\/App\/FrontController\/Plugin\/RequestPreprocessor.php:94]\n#12 Magento\\Store\\App\\FrontController\\Plugin\\RequestPreprocessor->aroundDispatch(&Magento\\Framework\\App\\FrontController\\Interceptor#0000000051f3c7a50000000073cc3fa5#, &Closure#0000000051f3c7830000000073cc3fa5#, &Magento\\Framework\\App\\Request\\Http#0000000051f3c66b0000000073cc3fa5#) called at [vendor\/magento\/framework\/Interception\/Interceptor.php:135]\n#13 Magento\\Framework\\App\\FrontController\\Interceptor->Magento\\Framework\\Interception\\{closure}(&Magento\\Framework\\App\\Request\\Http#0000000051f3c66b0000000073cc3fa5#) called at [vendor\/magento\/module-page-cache\/Model\/App\/FrontController\/BuiltinPlugin.php:73]\n#14 Magento\\PageCache\\Model\\App\\FrontController\\BuiltinPlugin->aroundDispatch(&Magento\\Framework\\App\\FrontController\\Interceptor#0000000051f3c7a50000000073cc3fa5#, &Closure#0000000051f3c7830000000073cc3fa5#, &Magento\\Framework\\App\\Request\\Http#0000000051f3c66b0000000073cc3fa5#) called at [vendor\/magento\/framework\/Interception\/Interceptor.php:135]\n#15 Magento\\Framework\\App\\FrontController\\Interceptor->Magento\\Framework\\Interception\\{closure}(&Magento\\Framework\\App\\Request\\Http#0000000051f3c66b0000000073cc3fa5#) called at [vendor\/magento\/framework\/Interception\/Interceptor.php:153]\n#16 Magento\\Framework\\App\\FrontController\\Interceptor->___callPlugins('dispatch', array(&Magento\\Framework\\App\\Request\\Http#0000000051f3c66b0000000073cc3fa5#), NULL) called at [generated\/code\/Magento\/Framework\/App\/FrontController\/Interceptor.php:26]\n#17 Magento\\Framework\\App\\FrontController\\Interceptor->dispatch(&Magento\\Framework\\App\\Request\\Http#0000000051f3c66b0000000073cc3fa5#) called at [vendor\/magento\/framework\/App\/Http.php:136]\n#18 Magento\\Framework\\App\\Http->launch() called at [generated\/code\/Magento\/Framework\/App\/Http\/Interceptor.php:24]\n#19 Magento\\Framework\\App\\Http\\Interceptor->launch() called at [vendor\/magento\/framework\/App\/Bootstrap.php:258]\n#20 Magento\\Framework\\App\\Bootstrap->run(&Magento\\Framework\\App\\Http\\Interceptor#0000000051f3c6240000000073cc3fa5#) called at [slp\/tienda1\/index.php:50]\n<\/pre>","url":"\/slp\/tienda1\/storeowner\/Index\/SendStoreOwnerForm\/","script_name":"\/slp\/tienda1\/index.php"}
```

I don´t get it.
This are my files:

Model

```
<?php
namespace Transom\Emall\Model;
class StoreOwner extends \Magento\Framework\Model\AbstractModel implements \Magento\Framework\DataObject\IdentityInterface
{
    const CACHE_TAG = 'store_owner_emall';

    protected $_cacheTag = 'store_owner_emall';

    protected $_eventPrefix = 'store_owner_emall';

    public function _construct()
    {
        $this->_init("Transom\Emall\Model\ResourceModel\StoreOwner");
    }

    public function getIdentities()
    {
        return [self::CACHE_TAG . '_' . $this->getId()];
    }

    public function getDefaultValues()
    {
        $values = [];

        return $values;
    }
}
```

ResourceModel:

```
<?php
namespace Transom\Emall\Model\ResourceModel;

class StoreOwner extends \Magento\Framework\Model\ResourceModel\Db\AbstractDb{

    public function __construct(\Magento\Framework\Model\ResourceModel\Db\Context $context)
    {
        parent::__construct($context);
    }

    protected function _construct()
    {
        $this->_init("store_owner_emall", "store_owner_id");
    }
}
```

Collection:

```
<?php
namespace Transom\Emall\Model\ResourceModel\StoreOwner;

class Collection extends \Magento\Framework\Model\ResourceModel\Db\Collection\AbstractCollection
{
    protected $_idFieldName = 'store_owner_id';
    protected $_eventPrefix = 'store_owner_emall_collection';
    protected $_eventObject = 'post_collection';

    /**
     * Define resource model
     *
     * @return void
     */
    protected function _construct()
    {
        $this->_init('Transom\Emall\Model\StoreOwner', 'Transom\Emall\Model\ResourceModel\StoreOwner');
    }

}
```

Custom table:

```
<?php

namespace Transom\Emall\Setup;

use Magento\Framework\Setup\InstallSchemaInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleContextInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\SchemaSetupInterface;

/**
*   @codeCoverageIgnore
*/
class InstallSchema implements InstallSchemaInterface
{
    public function install(SchemaSetupInterface    $setup, 
                            ModuleContextInterface  $context)
    {
        $installer = $setup;
        $installer->startSetup();
        $table = $installer->getConnection()
                            ->newTable($installer->getTable('store_owner_emall'))
                            ->addColumn(
                                    'store_owner_id',
                                    \Magento\Framework\DB\Ddl\Table::TYPE_INTEGER,
                                    null,
                                    ['identity' => true, 'unsigned' => true, 'nullable' => false, 'primary' => true],
                                    'Store Owner Id'
                            )
                            ->addColumn(
                                    'customer_name',
                                    \Magento\Framework\DB\Ddl\Table::TYPE_TEXT,
                                    null,
                                    ['unsigned' =>  true],
                                    'Customer'
                            )
                            ->addColumn(
                                    'business',
                                    \Magento\Framework\DB\Ddl\Table::TYPE_TEXT,
                                    null,
                                    ['nullable' =>  true],
                                    'Business Name'
                            )
                            ->addColumn(
                                    'business_line',
                                    \Magento\Framework\DB\Ddl\Table::TYPE_TEXT,
                                    null,
                                    ['nullable' =>  true],
                                    'Business Line'
                            )
                            ->addColumn(
                                'website_address',
                                \Magento\Framework\DB\Ddl\Table::TYPE_TEXT,
                                null,
                                ['nullable' =>  true],
                                'Website Address'
                            )
                            ->addColumn(
                                'facebook',
                                \Magento\Framework\DB\Ddl\Table::TYPE_TEXT,
                                null,
                                ['nullable' =>  true],
                                'Facebook'
                            )
                            ->addColumn(
                                'instagram',
                                \Magento\Framework\DB\Ddl\Table::TYPE_TEXT,
                                null,
                                ['nullable' =>  true],
                                'Instagram'
                            )
                            ->addColumn(
                                'email',
                                \Magento\Framework\DB\Ddl\Table::TYPE_TEXT,
                                null,
                                ['nullable' =>  true],
                                'Email'
                            )
                            ->addColumn(
                                'phone_number',
                                \Magento\Framework\DB\Ddl\Table::TYPE_TEXT,
                                null,
                                ['nullable' =>  true],
                                'Phone Number'
                            )
                            ->addColumn(
                                'business_phone_number',
                                \Magento\Framework\DB\Ddl\Table::TYPE_TEXT,
                                null,
                                ['nullable' =>  true],
                                'Business Phone Number'
                            )
                            ->addColumn(
                                'zip_code',
                                \Magento\Framework\DB\Ddl\Table::TYPE_TEXT,
                                null,
                                ['nullable' =>  true],
                                'Zip Code'
                            )
                            ->addColumn(
                                'state',
                                \Magento\Framework\DB\Ddl\Table::TYPE_TEXT,
                                null,
                                ['nullable' =>  true],
                                'State'
                            )
                            ->addColumn(
                                'city',
                                \Magento\Framework\DB\Ddl\Table::TYPE_TEXT,
                                null,
                                ['nullable' =>  true],
                                'City'
                            )
                            ->addColumn(
                                'suburb',
                                \Magento\Framework\DB\Ddl\Table::TYPE_TEXT,
                                null,
                                ['nullable' =>  true],
                                'Suburb'
                            )
                            ->addColumn(
                                    'created_at',
                                    \Magento\Framework\DB\Ddl\Table::TYPE_TIMESTAMP,
                                    null,
                                    ['nullable' =>  false],
                                    'Created At'
                            )
                            ->addIndex(
                                    $installer->getIdxName('store_owner_emall',  ['store_owner_id']),
                                    ['store_owner_id']
                            )
                            ->setComment('Store Owner Landingpage');
        $installer->getConnection()->createTable($table);
        $installer->endSetup();
    }
}
```

And Finally this is what I'm doing in order to store data in the controller:

```
       <?php

namespace Transom\Emall\Controller\Index;

use Magento\Framework\Mail\Template\TransportBuilder;
use Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action;
 use Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context;
 use Magento\Framework\View\Result\PageFactory;
 use Magento\Framework\Filesystem;
 use Magento\Framework\App\Filesystem\DirectoryList;
 use Magento\Framework\Controller\ResultFactory; 
use Psr\Log\LoggerInterface;
use Transom\Emall\Model\StoreOwner;
use Transom\Pakke\Logger\Logger;

class SendStoreOwnerForm extends Action
{
    
      /**
     * @var TransportBuilder
     */
    protected $transportBuilder;

    /**
     * @var LoggerInterface
     */
    protected $logger;

    /**
     * @var PageFactory
     */
    protected $resultPageFactory;

    /**
     * @var \Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface
     */
    protected $productRepository;

    /**
     * @var \Magento\Product\Model\ProductFactory
     */
    protected $productFactory;

    /**
     * @var \Magento\CatalogInventory\Api\StockRegistryInterface
     */
    protected $stockRegistry;
    /**
     * @var \Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface
     */
    private $storeManager;

    private $post;
    /**
     * @var Data
     */
    protected $customerSession;

    protected $_storeOwner;

    protected $_logger;

    /**
     * @param \Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface $storeManager
     * @param \Magento\Catalog\Api\ProductRepositoryInterface $productRepository ,
     * @param \Magento\Catalog\Api\Data\ProductInterfaceFactory $productFactory
     * @param \Magento\CatalogInventory\Api\StockRegistryInterface $stockRegistry
     * @param \Magento\MediaStorage\Model\File\UploaderFactory $fileUploaderFactory
     * @param Filesystem $filesystem
     * @param \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context $context
     * @param PageFactory $pageFactory
     * @param LoggerInterface $logger
     * @param TransportBuilder $transportBuilder
     * @param Data $customerSession
     * @param StoreOwner $storeOwner
     */
    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface $storeManager,
        \Magento\Catalog\Api\ProductRepositoryInterface $productRepository,
        \Magento\Catalog\Api\Data\ProductInterfaceFactory $productFactory,
        \Magento\CatalogInventory\Api\StockRegistryInterface $stockRegistry,
        \Magento\MediaStorage\Model\File\UploaderFactory $fileUploaderFactory,
        \Magento\Framework\Filesystem $filesystem,
        Context $context, 
        PageFactory $pageFactory,
        LoggerInterface $logger,
        TransportBuilder $transportBuilder,
        StoreOwner $storeOwner,
        Logger $loggerPakke

    ) {

        $this->logger = $logger;
        $this->transportBuilder = $transportBuilder;
        $this->storeManager     = $storeManager;
        $this->productRepository     = $productRepository;
        $this->productFactory  = $productFactory;
        $this->resultPageFactory = $pageFactory;
        $this->stockRegistry = $stockRegistry;
        $this->_storeOwner = $storeOwner;
        $this->_logger = $loggerPakke;

        parent::__construct($context);
    }
  
    public function execute()
    {
        $post = $this->getRequest()->getPostValue();
        $model = $this->_storeOwner->create();

        $formData = array(
            'name'=>$post["name"],
            'business'=>$post["business"],
            'business_line'=>$post["business_line"],
            'website_address'=>$post["web_address"],
            'facebook'=>$post["facebook"],
            'instagram'=>$post["instagram"],
            'email'=>$post["email"],
            'phone_number'=>$post["telephone"],
            'business_phone_number'=>$post["telephone_business"],
            'zip_code'=>$post["zip_code"],
            'state'=>$post["state"],
            'city'=>$post["city"],
            'suburb'=>$post["suburb"]
        );

      /*Send email to admin*/
      
      $receiverInfo = [
        'name' => 'Admin',
        'email' => 'ovazquez@transom-group.com'
        ];

        $emails = ['ovazquez@transom-group.com']; //users that will receive the email

        $store = $this->storeManager->getStore();

        $transport = $this->transportBuilder->setTemplateIdentifier(
            'Transom_Emall_Store_Owner'
        )->setTemplateOptions(
            ['area' => 'frontend', 'store' => $store->getId()]
        )->addTo(
            $emails, $receiverInfo['name']
        )->setTemplateVars(
            $formData
        )->setFrom(
            'general'
        )->getTransport();


        try {
            // Send an email
            $transport->sendMessage();
            $model->addData([
                'name'=>$post["name"],
                'business'=>$post["business"],
                'business_line'=>$post["business_line"],
                'website_address'=>$post["web_address"],
                'facebook'=>$post["facebook"],
                'instagram'=>$post["instagram"],
                'email'=>$post["email"],
                'phone_number'=>$post["telephone"],
                'business_phone_number'=>$post["telephone_business"],
                'zip_code'=>$post["zip_code"],
                'state'=>$post["state"],
                'city'=>$post["city"],
                'suburb'=>$post["suburb"]
            ]);
            $modelSaved = $model->save();
            if($modelSaved){
                $this->logger->info("Model was saved!!");
                
            }
            else{
                $this->logger->info("Model was not saved!!");
            }
            
        } catch (\Exception $e) {
            // Write a log message whenever get errors
            $this->logger->critical($e->getMessage());
        }
        
    }
}
```

I don't get what is wrong whit this,
greetings!

Comment: Share the code of entire controller

Comment: @DhirenVasoya done. please check

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I can see you already created custom model for managing or interacting with custom database table.

Model class is : \Transom\Emall\Model\StoreOwner

So, use this class as factory class in your controller's __construct method as per below.

```
protected $_storeOwner;

public function __construct(\Transom\Emall\Model\StoreOwnerFactory $storeowner)
{
     $this->_storeOwner = $storeowner;
}


public function execute()
{
    // create a payload array of your data where key consist column name and value consist value for that columns

    $modelPayload['col1'] = $val1;
    $modelPayload['col2'] = $val2;
    $modelPayload['col3'] = $val3;
    $modelPayload['col4'] = $val4;
    
    $stobj = $_storeOwner->create();

    $stobj = $stobj->setData($modelPayload)->save();
}
```